# CSS floating behavior

Tags: html, css

I am making a `div`(red) that acts as a menu (screenshot 1), but when I add `float:right;` to the css the footer pops to the top on the page (screenshot 2)

---

*Screen Shot 1:*
[image: screenshot1]

*Screen Shot 2:*
[image: screenshot2]

---

#### CSS:

```
.right-menu {
float:right;
width:10em;
height:35em;
background:red;/*temporary*/
padding:10px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="right-menu">
    <form class="login">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="User Name"/><br>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/><br>
    </form>
    <form class="search">
        <input type="text" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" placeholder="Search">
        <div id="livesearch"></div>
    </form>
    <a href="<? echo $siteAddress ?>download/password">Password</a><br>
    <a href="<? echo $siteAddress ?>support/contact">Contact</a><br>
    <a href="<? echo $siteAddress ?>support/help">Help</a><br>
    <a href="<? echo $siteAddress ?>legal/policy">Policy</a><br>
    <a href="<? echo $siteAddress ?>legal/terms">TOS</a><br>
    <a href="<? echo $siteAddress ?>support/adds">Adds</a><br>
</div>
```

Any idea whats happening?

*p.s. using firefox*

Comment: Do you clear the float anywhere?

Comment: So...not a **glitch** but rather **default behaviour**!

Comment: More "Exactly what you are asking for" rather than either of those ;)

Comment: @Paulie_D -- I know. didn't know what else to call it. Does the title change satisfy you?

Comment: @Paulie_D is pure savage today, seen him on multiple posts putting the world to rights! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea whats happening?

`float` means "Move to the side. Put any content after this element on the other side instead of below."

Use the `clear` property to tell content not to move up beside a floated element.

```
#footer {
    clear: right; /* or both */
}
```